# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: support, editing

Recently, I came across [this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215413/can-you-find-a-way-to-get-rid-of-it-your-gamer-tag-minecraft-pe-for-tablet)

[image]

I wanted to edit it because of obvious reasons. The title was bad, the question was bad and there was irrelevant text in it. Also, it had the wrong tag.

But, sadly, I could not edit it. The edit button was greyed out and was no longer a link. So my question is, **why can't I edit this question?**

It can't be my edit history, as I have 32 edits accepted and only 1 rejected. But I had submitted a few edits before this recently that may not have been approved yet. So is there a limit on the number of pending edit suggestions you can have? But then that doesn't make sense since 5 mins later an edit was approved but I still couldn't edit this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because there's already an active suggested edit pending for the question. The system doesn't allow you to edit an edit (there's too many cases to handle for a relatively rare occurrence), it simply disables the option.

There are a few other conditions which will disable the button. Here's the Meta Stack Exchange faq entry on it: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)